# JavaScript - play audio returned by GET

Tags: javascript, ajax, audio

I try to create a webapp that reads texts using google translate's tts. Opening the following URL results in an audio file: https://translate.google.co.uk/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&q=hello%20world&tl=en&total=1&idx=0&textlen=11&prev=input

How can I play this media in a webapp? (turning off same origin policy is an acceptable compromise)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way:

```
var audio;

audio = new Audio();
audio.onloadeddata = function () {
    audio.play();
};
audio.src = url; // put your url here
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the event is onloadeddata, I accept your answer once its changed